# Easiest way to mask a URL in the address bar?

Tags: javascript, url

I have a page, "http://www.somedomain.com/page.php/". What's the easiest way to show it as "http://www.somedomain.com/blahblahblah", or even "http://www.somedomain.com/page.php?blahblahblah". And when you enter that new URL in an address bar, it doesn't bring anything up?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose if it doesn't bring anything up?

Comment: do make sure that there are actual pages there so that a refresh will work

Comment: `history.replaceState(null, null,  "/blahblahblah")`

Comment: @dandavis tisk tisk, you should have posted that as an answer.